# PHP MYSQL, How to show records in four columns ,

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code the records shows in four columns but if my records is blank it shows three balng images, any suggestions?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from rbf_events_images where event_id='".$_GET['id']."'");
echo '<table border="1">';
if(count(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)):
$tropentags='<tr>';
$troclosingtags='</tr>';
$formTags="";
$tdTags="";
$count=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$tdTags.='<td align="left" valign="middle" class="td" >$row['image']</td>';

if ($count>3)
    {
   $formTags.=$tropentags.$tdTags.$troclosingtags;
   $tdTags="";
   $count=0;
    }
    $count=$count+1;
  }
if ($count>0)
{
  for($i = 1; $i <= (4-$count) ; $i++)
  {
$tdTags.='<td align="left" valign="middle" class="td"  >$row['image']</td>'; 
  }
  $formTags.=$tropentags.$tdTags.$troclosingtags;
}

echo $formTags;  


endif;
```

Thanks for your help!really appreciated!

Comment: Can you improve your code to be readable? Indent with four spaces the code, and it will be displayed correctly.

Comment: @MainMa - edited on @devzone's behalf :)

Comment: It's still unreadable, but now for the other reason (refactoring etc.).

Comment: Rather than using double quotes, you could use \" to display the double quotes properly when the code is rendered to HTML.

Rather than $count = $count + 1, you could just have a line that says $count++; - it does the same thing.

Why are you piecing together the tables? You could save characters and increase readability if you just used echo() or printf() to output your HTML.

The logic you're using in the for loop doesn't seem right. $i <= (4-$count) will never evaluate properly once the count gets past 3. Will it ever get past 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I usually do to put records in columns:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from rbf_events_images where event_id='$id'");
echo '<table border="1"><tbody><tr>';
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $count = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        if ($count && $count % 4 == 0) echo '</tr><tr>';
        echo '<td align="left" valign="middle" class="td">'.$row['image'].'</td>';
        $count++;
    }
}
echo '</tr></tbody></table>';
```

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you found it helpful! If you actually used my answer, it would be awesome if you could mark my answer as accepted (this will increase your reputation points). Good luck on the project!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that on lines like this one:

```
$tdTags.='<td align="left" valign="middle" class="td" >$row['image']</td>';
```

You are delimiting the string with single quotes ('), and you are also trying to embed a variable in the string that uses single quotes. I'm not sure how you did not get compile errors for that. I would switch to:

```
$tdTags= '<td align="left" valign="middle" class="td">' . $row['image'] . '</td>';
```

Comment: To be more specific, it doesn't matter if there's an index or not, as anything in single quotes has literal output and doesn't parse variables.  `'Some text $var more text'` just outputs exactly as it's written: Some text $var more text.